# Why does Deadpool always have a yellow speech bubble?

Tags: marvel, comics, deadpool

When Deadpool was created and introduced by Rob Liefeld, he was a quirky assassin, but spoke with normal speech bubbles (colors matching everyone else in the scene).

Every time I've seen him in anything recent, his speech (inner monologue and external dialogue with other characters) is always in a yellow speech bubble distinctively different from everyone else in the scene.

Why are his speech bubbles colored differently?

[image: Deadpool's speech bubbles]

Comment: It's interesting to note that some characters have unique speech indicated by a special font (in Marvel, Asgardians for instance; the Thing's speech has also used a special font on occasion). I tend to think of that as indicating a distinction in how the character's voice actually sounds (not the words used, but something distinctive about the sound of the voice itself). I want to say that this was done with word balloons in the 90s as well (remembering Human Torch balloons with little flames added); could be from the same time, and easy enough to do to continue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In comics, unusual speech bubble shapes or colors indicate that there is something different about the way the character talks.  This convention goes back to the earliest Action Comics (if not earlier) where 'translated from *language name*' words were italicized, giving them a very different appearance.

It's used to indicate that Deadpool's method of speech is instantly recognizable to anyone who hears it.  I've also seen it indicated that his 'little yellow boxes' are also speech bubbles - he simply thinks it's an internal monologue.

Comment: Has his speech changed since he was introduced? Why did the yellow boxes begin later?

Comment: As with many characters, Deadpool has changed over time.  With the merc with a mouth, he's gotten significantly crazier, to the point where he now believes himself to be a character in a comic book that is being read by an invisible, intangible audience.  He's even gone so far as to address them, in the past.  His speech bubbles changed as he got crazier.

Comment: And the "little yellow boxes" vary as to whether others can hear them. Honestly, the only time I remember non-telepaths reacting to them was one issue where he confused which was which, so he was speaking his internal monologue and thinking what he thought he was speaking, confusing everyone, including himself.

Comment: I wonder what level of crazy will make it into the movie...

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question so much as punts it. What is so unique about DP's speech to merit consistent use of yellow speech bubbles? The answer doesn't attempt to answer that.

Comment: @JDoe: How would you respond?  You are welcome to provide your own answer.  I, myself, do not know what would be distinctive about his speech and was unwilling to provide an unsubstantiated guess.  The excellent film, which contained an entirely appropriate level of crazy, did nothing to clarify it either.

Comment: If I don't have enough information to provide an answer, I just don't. If I think I can add something useful to aid in finding an answer, I'd leave that in a comment. If I am familiar enough with the relevant material to consider myself an authority and don't know the answer, I would cite that absence of evidence as evidence of absence, i.e. there probably is no answer. Believe me, I've started a lot of answers that end up being comments because halfway through I realize that I'm just punting.

Comment: It's at least possible that the unique speech balloons actually do represent something unique about how Wade's speech sounds. We know that his body is constantly healing (and taking fresh damage from) cancer (or something similar). It might be possible that this on-going damage has affected his vocal chords. I'm not aware of anything that explicitly backs up this theory, though.

Answer (score 4):

The different colored boxes that appear in the comic books were introduced to show Deadpool's increasing descent into insanity. So far, he has dealt with two voices: the 'Yellow Box' referenced in the question is a child-like, smart-assed, highly excitable voice that rarely thinks before voicing its opinions. The second voice, the 'White Box', although sarcastic in his own way, he tends to use more logic and carefully thinks things through. It should be noted that he also tends to want a degree of distance from Deadpool and the 'Yellow Box', as referenced in the High Moon Studios video game Deadpool, where he states 'Y'know, time apart could really help this relationship. Just saying'."

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  An interesting answer, but if you could provide some specific examples, it would be a much better answer

Comment: Note: the OP was asking why Deadpool's speech bubbles are yellow. The "thought boxes" are a separate issue.

Answer (score 2):

If by recent, you mean anything in the last two decades. Deadpool's yellow speech bubbles started in his first solo title. The prior limited mini series like The Circle Chase and sins of the past had white bubbles with a yellow border. I can't recall if any of his appearances prior to Deadpool Vol. 1 Issue 1 had the yellow bubbles, in X-Force at the time.

Unique speech bubbles or thought boxes are shorthand for the audience to tell certain aspects of the characters both in and out of universe. In Deadpool's case, it's that he's very weird in universe. Other characters also have unique bubbles. Cable is often blue. Superman had yellow while batman has blue, green lantern green in some of the pre Flashpoint Justice League comics.

His little yellow boxes, meant to be internal monologue, are also spoken, as Deadpool can't keep his internal thoughts to himself. Oh what fun he has with his little yellow boxes. Due to Deadpool being considered a Crack pot, people just ignore this as crazy babbling.

As of Vol. 3 written by Daniel Way, some bastard white boxes have shown up, supposedly both Deadpool second internal voice or the Arthur, Way, interacting with him. They suck.

Comment: Unique thought boxes became important when comics moved away from simply using thought balloons (which had a trail of bubbles pointing to the head of the thinker, just like speech balloons have a comma-like pointer to the speaker. By avoiding the need to tie the thought to the thinker, much longer thoughts were also allowed (as they could be moved to the edge of the panels where they wouldn't obscure the art as much).

Answer (score -1):

Actually, your answers are wrong.
The different colored boxes are "voices" in his head. This is all explained in "Deadpool Kills the Marvel Universe."

Comment: Please do not insult other people's answers.  I know you cite a source, but can you provide some evidence e.g. a quote or image?

Comment: The "voices" seem to be talking to other people, then, as the text bubbles in normal conversation with other people are also colored differently.

Answer (score -1):

It's true that it's to show a unique voice, but whenever someone's *dressed* as Deadpool, they have yellow text, and I imagine their voice might be different.

Comment: Could you [edit] to add in information on this?

Answer (score -2):

I'm fairly certain that the voices are actually two different protagonists in the marvel universe, conversing to both one another and Wade, driving him to his decent to madness. While I do know some comics supported this, I can't remember which. So, I may as well be as credible as a goose, but It's my two cents. It is just another possibility, however, given that your other theories are just as likely.

Comment: This is discussing the "thought boxes", not the yellow speech bubbles as demonstrated in the page included in the original post.